# definitional extension vs. $\lambda$-abstraction

Tags: logic, type-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a first-order language in signature $\Sigma$ and $\mathcal{L^+}$ an extension of $\mathcal{L}$ in a richer signature $\Sigma^+$. An $\mathcal{L^+}$-theory $T^+$ is a definitional extension of $\mathcal{L}$-theory $T$ if $T^+=T\cup\{\theta_i\}$. $\theta_i$ are definitional sentences of the form
$$\forall \bar{x}(p(\bar{x})\leftrightarrow\phi(\bar{x}))$$
where $p\in\Sigma^+$ and $\phi(\bar{x})$ is a $\Sigma$-formula.

My question is: is there an analogue of definitional extension in type theory with $\lambda$-abstraction? I am asking because it appears that, given the abstraction devise for forming new predicates, a theory automatically has a very rich syntax and it is not immediate to me that the theory can have nontrivial definitional extensions (in other words, is there anything that the definitional sentence can do that cannot be achieved by $\lambda$-abstraction?)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "$\beta$-abstraction"?

Comment: @RobArthan sorry my bad it should have been $\lambda$-abstraction (I was thinking of $\beta$-conversion)